# Get Global Variables in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, global-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a jenkins pipeline which is used on different environments / builds. Each Build has different parameters: deploy destination, passwords, usernames etc.

I have some common settings all these builds share, which i have added in the "Jenkins" -> "Configuration" -> "Global properties" as a key value.

Lets say i have added a key value par with : 
Name : CommonName
Value : Money

I now want to be able to, in my pipeline, to access this CommonName variable.
I've tried everything.

```
println "{$params.CommonName}"
println "{$env.CommonName}"
println "{$CommonName}"
```

Nothing returns me the value from the global configuration.

Not even have a parameter key value on the build to be like: 
Name : Name
Value : ${CommonName}

And then trying to access "${params.Name}", still null in return.

Baseline is, i want to have shared variables across different builds, which i can alter in Jenkins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
println "${env.CommonName}"
println "${CommonName}"
```

It should if you move the $-character. 
I've tried the following and both work:

```
println GLOBAL_VAR
println env.GLOBAL_VAR
```

Prints

```
[Pipeline] echo
global_var_value
[Pipeline] echo
global_var_value
```

Comment: Thank you! - Could you explain a bit further this is?

Comment: What part? To insert att variable in a string, the correct what to do it is ${variable/command} not "{$variable}". Besides that, jenkins pipeline inserts variables so they are accessible in the script, that way you can skip env if you want to. So println GLOBAL_VAR is the same as println "${GLOBAL_VAR}"