# How to work with configuration information in Jenkins instead of hard-coding in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /PR-\d+-head/ && env.CHANGE_TARGET == 'QA_branch' )){
  sh """
      sfdx force:source:deploy --url https://abc.salesforce.com
  """
}else if(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ /PR-\d+-head/ && env.CHANGE_TARGET == 'UAT_branch' )){
  sh """
      sfdx force:source:deploy --url https://def.salesforce.com
  """
}
```

I have Jenkinsfile similar to this. These urls keep changing and I have to update Jenkinsfile every time new url is generated by salesforce.
Is there a way to store this kind of information in Jenkins and read from Jenkins? Like we do for storing credentials.

I can store these urls in Jenkins as credentials and get those values in Jenkinsfile but not sure if that is a good approach as these are not credentials.
I am looking for a way to avoid updating Jenkinsfile every time environment related information changes and move it to Jenkins or somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store these URLs as global properties and access them in your jenkinsfile as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585958/get-global-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (more complicated) is to stored a file in a source control, and let Jenkins download the file, read the data within the file and read the URL's.

Good things about this approach:

- Your config code is versioned
- Your config code resides outside jenkins, so it is easy to backup
- You can config files on different branches, so you use what you need

The only drawback is that you need more coding to implement this solution.